# Ray shadows are not correct

Tags: lighting, shadows

I created a simple scene with a plane, a mountain and some trees. I added a sun and selected "Ray shadows", but the shadows are created like if the sun is right above the scene. It's not where I positioned the sun and I even tried different positions, but the shadows never change.
What do I need to do to have working shadows?

Blender v2.79
Blender Render

[image: The rendered preview of the scene with wrong shadows.]

[image: The settings of the sun]

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? What render engine? Could you post some screenshots?

Comment: Didn't know I could upload pictures. I'm sorry, edited the post with more infos!

Comment: Have you rotated you sun lamp? Sun lamps are always calculated as if at an infinite distance, unless you give it some rotation their poisition in the scene is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. Didn't know I had to give it a direction. So basically if I don't give it a direction it's like if it's always above everything?

Comment: Note also that no lamp in Blender Internal will give shadows except Spot unless enabling Ray tracing in Render tab > Shading rollout

Comment: A sun lamp by default points straight down, so yes, unless you rotate it, it will be shining from right above everything. Moreover, regardless of where you place it, it's always calculated from "outside" the scene, at infinite distance. In essence, you can safely leave it at the world origin and control the light/shadows by rotating it.

Comment: @MrZak It was checked by default

Comment: In default Blender Internal Ray Tracing isn't checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>(Others have mentioned this in comments, but the question still has no answer. I am writing this for other people that might run into the problem in the future.)</sub>

The position of the sun has no effect on the direction the light is coming from. This is because the `sun` light is meant to simulate a light source that is infinitely far away. This gives an effect very close to that given by our actual sun, since the real sun is *very* far away.

Instead, to control the direction the light is falling from, rotate your sun object. Example:

**Straight down**

[image: Down]

**Rotated**

[image: Rotated]

Note that it doesn't matter where you put the sun. It could even be positioned behind the object. It is always going to give light that appears to be coming from far away, opposite the direction you have pointed it in.